# Why are the definite articles "la" and "les" necessary when saying "raffoler de la tarte aux pommes"?

Tags: articles

It's not that he likes any specific tart or specific apples in it, but he likes tarts in general and apples in general. So I'm confused about the reason.

> - Il raffole de la tarte aux pommes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlike in English, the definite article in French isn't intrinsically specific, and is in fact obligatory when a generic meaning is intended.

To mark specificity, we usually use a demonstrative or possessive determiner, both of which mark a noun phrase as specific:

> Il raffole de ta tarte aux pommes.
>
> Il raffole de cette tarte aux pommes.
>
> Il raffole de cette tarte-là.

The definite article can be both generic or specific, but its normal reading is generic. You'd need some other element to mark a noun phrase with a definite article as specific, generally some kind of nominal or phrasal complement:

> Il raffole de la tarte aux pommes de sa grand-mère
>
> Il raffole de la tarte aux pommes que tu lui a cuisinée

(In both cases, an English translation would use a definite article here, rather than the zero article used with generics)

In some cases, doubling pronouns can be used to disambiguate between generic and specific:

> Les chiens, ça aboie (Dogs bark - generic)
>
> Les chiens, ils aboient (the dogs are barking - specific)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few cases where ***la*** can be dropped:

> *C'est lui qui a pris le plus **de** tarte aux pommes* (follows quantity adverb)
>
> *Il ne veux pas **de** tarte aux pommes* (negative sentence, *de la* is also possible here)
>
> *Il s'est [gavé](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/gaver) **de** tarte aux pommes* (*[de](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/de/0)* = preposition, colloquial, means "he force-fed himself with apple-pie")

Comment: No partitive article here. The *de* is a preposition required by the verb's valence (you can't say "il raffole la tarte") and a partitive sentence would be "Il rafolle de tarte aux pommes" where the partitive article is deleted to avoid a double *de*

Comment: @Eauquidort You are right, thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 0):

There is never "in general" in french. We need always an article to define the object. For example : "he likes apples" will give : "Il aime **les** pommes". We will never say "Il aime pommes".